# Creating an object only to subscribe to others object's events

Tags: c#, oop, events, event-handling

I believe my question is not language specific.

I have a class, say `EventConsumer`, that needs to listen to others object events, say `EventProducer`, (to .Net `Form` events to be precise) and react appropriately, so one of it's constructor parameters is that object (`public EventConsumer(EventProducer producer, ...)`). In constructor I subscribe to producer's events and that's pretty much it. I don't really need to keep reference to consumer. It'll be garbage collected when the event producer will be too.

So is it OK, to have such a strange line in the code that looks like it does nothing? Eg.:

```
new EventObserver(eventConsumer, config);
```

Is it a right way to do? Isn't that a little odd?

Comment: I would suggest using a framework like [Reactive Extensions](http://rx.codeplex.com/); here free online [book](http://introtorx.com/). For common usage patterns: [Extensions to Reactive Extensions](http://rxx.codeplex.com/). Hope can help.

Comment: You can create an Event in EventProducer and subscribe to that event from EventConsumer... Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that object creation on it's own is odd -- it will almost certainly confuse you (or other developers) when looking at the code in 6 months time.

I would make it more 'friendly' by adding a static method to your `EventObserver` class to do the instance creation:

```
public static CreateObserver(EventProducer eventProducer)
{
    // Create new instance of EventObserver to handle events from producer
    //  no need to keep track of object as it will be appropriately 
    //  garbage collected.
    new EventOvserver(eventProducer);
}
```

Then you're calling code is the neater:

```
EventObserver.CreateObserver(eventProducer);
```

Comment: Yeah, this looks much friendlier, and the comment inside clarifies it even more. Thanks!